# Update Custom Object within Array using a key

Tags: ios, objective-c

The title can be a little unclear. But here is what i want to achieve:

I have an `NSMutableArray` with custom object e.g.

```
[
Custom Object 1,
Custom Object 2,
Custom Object 3,
..
..
..
Custom Object 10
]
```

The `Custom object` Consists of following variables:

```
id, name, date, seen_count;
```

I have the value of `id` e.g.`10`.

Now I want get the `Index` of the `custom object` where `id=10` within `NSMutableArray`, so that i can update that object and reload a particular `Row/Cell` within `UITableView` to reflect the changes.

**P.S:** One way to do is to loop through the array. But is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Use NSPredicate::**

```
CustomObject *object= [[[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 10"]] lastObject];

// make changes in object.
```

**Get Index of Object in array::**

```
NSUInteger positionOfChange =  [yourArray indexOfObject:object];

// update your cell that is on position positionOfChange integer value
```

Hope this will help and sorry for any typo in code snippet.

**Note ::** if you are not confirm that object will always there for id than first check that filtered array has object and then go further otherwise it will crash. **Don't check lastobject in filteredArrayUsingPredicate if you are not sure.**

Answer (score 2):

Since an array can only be accessed by index, iterating through the array is the only way.  You can loop explicitly, looking for the appropriate object or implicitly using the `indexOfObjectPassingTest` method of `NSArray`.  The advantage of this approach is that it only has to iterate as far as the first match, while `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` needs to iterate the whole array.

```
NSInteger objectIndex=[myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    CustomObject *myObject=(CustomObject *)obj;
    if (obj.id==targetid) {   // Assumes id is an int, change the test as appropriate if it is a string or other object
        *stop=YES;
    }
}];
```

Another approach is to use an auxiliary NSDictionary that stores the index of the object.  This requires a single iteration of the array to build the dictionary but allows you to locate a given object more quickly.

For convenience I will assume that id in this case is a string; if it is an int then you need to box it in an NSNumber:

```
NSMutableDictionary auxDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (i=0;i<myArray.count;i++) {  
   CustomObject *obj=myArray[i];
   [auxDict addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:obj.id];
}
```

Then, to access an object, simply use the dictionary

```
NSNumber *indexNumber=auxDict[targetId];
int index=[indexNumber intValue];
CustomObject *object=myArray[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *search=@"5";
    NSInteger index=-1;
    if ([[arr valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:search]) {
        index=[arr1 indexOfObject:search];

    }
    if (index!=-1) {
        //do whatever with your index
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your answer?

Comment: This is a fairly inefficient solution - first it creates a new array that contains the value of the `id` property of the objects in the first array, then it checks to see if the desired `id` is in this new array (iterating the array in the process), then it obtains the index of the matching object (iterating the array again) making it O3n.  You could simply use `indexOfObject` to start with and check for the special result `NSNotFound` rather than using `containsObject` but that will still make it O2n

Comment: You can simply do it with creating new array. This would also make it O2n.